# Continuously spin a matrix of objects in Processing

Tags: python, processing

I have a bunch of lines that draw a composite circle. I want to make this composite circle spin continuously but can't figure it out. To further explain what I want, it will be kinda like a loading spinner.

```
def setup():
    size(640, 640)
    frameRate(30)

def draw():
    background(0)
    stroke(100, 100, 100)
    strokeWeight(4)
    translate(width/2, height/2)

    # I want to rotate/make this composite circle spin continuously
    make_circle()


def make_circle():
    inner_radius = width / 8
    line_length = width / 3
    rx = sqrt(2) * inner_radius
    ry = rx

    steps = 10
    pushMatrix()
    for dtheta in range(0, 360, steps):
        dtheta = radians(dtheta)
        coss = cos(dtheta)
        sinn = sin(dtheta)
        
        line(inner_radius * coss, inner_radius * sinn, line_length * coss, line_length * sinn)
    popMatrix()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [`rotate`](https://processing.org/reference/rotate_.html) the complete shape. Add an `angle` variable in global namespace. Increment the `angle` inn every frame and [`rotate`](https://processing.org/reference/rotate_.html) the shape by the angle (by default the unit of the angle is radians):

```py
angle = 0

def draw():
    global angle
    
    background(0)
    stroke(100, 100, 100)
    strokeWeight(4)
    translate(width/2, height/2)
    
    rotate(radians(angle))
    angle += 1
    make_circle()
```

[image]